# Why does Eclipse compile unusable broken classes when there is an error in the code?

Tags: eclipse

I've tried to Google this matter unsuccesfully so I registered just to ask this.
I use "Build Automatically" in Eclipse. It's not just one time that I have deployed a class file with compilation errors. Why? Because there is basicly only a little tiny red box in the corner to "tell me" if there is a compilation error. On top of that it nicely creates a nice looking class file ready to go.

I either want:

1. The useless broken class file not to be there at all in case it wasn't possible to properly compile it
2. Giant warning/error dialog that there is a compilation error in my code after I have saved

Is either possible? I've Googled, I've browsed the settings, nothing.. 
Sorry my general "attitude" on this post but this particular issue just irritates me!

Comment: The question in the title is based on the wrong assumption that an empty or incomplete class cannot be used; (1) Check the checkbox at the bottom of _Project > Properties: Java Compiler > Error/Warnings_; (2) If the red error markers already shown while typing are not enough, enable _Code Minings_ (showing a dialog is a bad idea since this would block your workflow).

Answer (score 0):

I can sympathize with your concern, as I have often seen colleagues who are newer to software development inadvertently push files with compile errors to our source control.  However, there is more than just the one tiny little red box that tells you there is a compilation error.  That "tiny little red box" appears in multiple places, and results in additional "are you sure" prompts along the way.

You'll see a red mark in the file, in the Project/Package Explorer, and in the Problems view.  In addition, if you are using git in Eclipse, if the file with compile errors is visible in the staging view, the red mark will be on that file entry also.  Also, if you attempt to run the application locally, a prompt will come up telling you that the project has compilation errors.

Despite all that, note the comment from @howlger, pointing out that a class with compile errors can still possibly be used.  The Eclipse Java compiler is very intelligent.  If you end up with a compile error in one method in a class, but you run tests that don't go through that method, then you may not be affected, so it allows for that possibility.